# how to bind the function in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, jestjs

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  loadData() {
    return {
      valueA: this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'app.placeHolder'}),
      valueB: this.getTheValue
    };
  }
  getTheValue(value) {
    return this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'app.placeHolder'}, {price: value});
  }

  render() {
    return <Child data={this.loadData()} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.data.valueB(1000)}</div>;
  }
}
```

i have the above code , i want to use `getTheValue` function in child component.here i need to bind `getTheValue` function in the parent.i am using following 2 ways to bind

```
1)  getTheValue = (value) => {
return this.props.someFunc('placeHolder', value);
}
```

or

```
2) valueB: () => this.getTheValue()
```

the main problem is , am getting the following error with these 2 ways.

```
[ 'Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component\'s constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.' ]
```

i am wondering is this error related to binding ? am i binding correctly ?
code works fine with one these ways but i am getting the error when i run the test but passing the tests with out any issue . but i want to remove the error.

Comment: The arrow function you have should be binding correctly. The error means you are somehow calling a state update within your render function

Answer (score 0):

What is this.props.someFunc('placeHolder', value) doint? Is it mutating the state?

Comment: that is actually 
this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'app.placeHolder'}, {price: value});

using reactIntl formatmessage function

Comment: code works fine with one these ways but i am getting the error when i run the test but passing the tests with out any issue . but i want to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is fine

In `parent`, you are updating state in the render function by calling `this.loadData()`

You might want to restructure how you are loading data in the component. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    someService.loadData().then(data => {
      this.setState(data)
    });
  }

  dataIsLoaded() {
    //... check this.state to see if data is loaded
  }

  render() {
    return this.dataIsLoaded
      ? <Child data={this.state.data}
      : <p>Loading</p>
  }
}
```

Comment: i am guessing the same but how to bind it . i followed 2 ways but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In parent you are calling loadData() which gets executed as part of the child rendering operation and loadData is creating the object at that time by calling someFunc - so props are changing while Child is being rendered.

Try something like this:

```
  render() {
    let data = this.loadData();
    return <Child data={data} />;
  }
```

Comment: I think we may need to know more about "someFunc"

Comment: here is the 
actual someFunc -> this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'app.placeHolder'}, {price: value});

Comment: this keeps going up the parent tree. I am sorry I wasn't able to help but I think this has some fundamental problems - I don't think a child should recursively climb so high up the render tree to get its props back. You may want to look at something like Redux to keep intl in a global store or something similar.